# Word With Similar Meaning to Wiki but Not Community Driven

Tags: word-choice

I want to add essentially add a series of informational pages and pages that I will add to overtime.  It will be a Sub-domain of the existing site.  A am looking for a good word to call this Sub-domain and the site menu button to get to it.

I am hoping that these pages may in the future be used by Engineering and students. It will contain information on standards, facts and design recommendations.

I initially had planned on 'Wiki' but this will not be open to the general public for editing.  The site will look very much like a wiki type site where a page containing information will link to several pages with similar relevant information.  Other words I have brainstormed were: Information, Info, Design Info, Resources, Library.

Comment: *Documentation* or *Reference* could be used here.

Comment: Both of those are good options.  I was also thinking of Blog but the look, feel and navigation of the site would not match popular blog layouts.

Comment: You call it whatever you like, really. Students will click the link you tell them to, and as long as it's *somewhat* descriptive, the exact word won't really matter.

Comment: I think the word for a website where people go for information that isn't editable is 'website'. If that sounds wrong, maybe you could explain in what ways this website is like a wiki?

Comment: A website means a collection of webpages on the web but there are websites and names for those websites that exist for different purposes.  Often different pages or collections of pages on a website will serve different purposes and be given different names.  For example an "About" collection of pages will often describe why the website, individual, company exists and what their purpose is.  A "Contact" collection of pages will describe how best to communicate with the individual or company.  A "Blog" will often contain opinions or announcements.  All of these can exist as part of a website.

Comment: I am looking for a good name for a subsection of a website that may already contain other subsections such as "About", "Services", "Contact", "Blog", etc.  The name will describe a learning/information part of the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Wikis" don't technically have to be publicly editable. From Wikipedia:

> A [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki) is a web application which allows people to add, modify, or delete content in collaboration with others.

The point of a wiki is collaboration and a set of "evolving" documentation. Even if there is only one actual editor, if the wiki *could* be edited or maintained by a team due to using wiki software it could be classified as a wiki.

But avoiding the term due to its common association with *publicly editable* wikis is completely legitimate. The most common term I hear in its place is "knowledge base". From Wikipedia:

> Knowledge management products adopted the term "[knowledge-base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_base)" to describe their repositories but the meaning had a subtle difference [from its original meaning]. In the case of previous knowledge-based systems the knowledge was primarily for the use of an automated system, to reason about and draw conclusions about the world. **With knowledge management products the knowledge was primarily meant for humans, for example to serve as a repository of manuals, procedures, policies, best practices, reusable designs and code, etc.** Of course in both cases the distinctions between the uses and kinds of systems were ill defined. As the technology scaled up it was rare to find a system that could really be cleanly classified as knowledge-based in the sense of an expert system that performed automated reasoning and **knowledge-based in the sense of knowledge management that provided knowledge in the form of documents and media that could be leveraged by humans.**

If you read the full article, you can see that the term "knowledge base" has a tumultuous history but its current usage in the realm of documentation is fairly clear. It means a set of documents that serve as a "database of knowledge" about a particular topic.

The major differences between a wiki and a knowledge-base are (a) its intent and (b) how the information is catalogued and maintained.

Wikis:

- Document and categorize virtually anything on a particular topic but do not typically cover *everything* on a particular topic and are intended to be a starting point or launching pad -- often filled with links to learn more
- Are typically maintained "on-the-fly" and tend to slowly adopt information as it becomes available or is discovered
- Typically has many editors that make small edits

Knowledge-bases:

- Attempt to fully document a particular area or topic
- Are categorized by "problem" in order to present quick an accurate solutions to common questions or issues
- Typically have full articles created by an expert that thoroughly addresses everything necessary to understand the topic
- Articles are only loosely maintained once created and posted
- Typically has fewer editors and they make very large changes at once

Some quick examples of the differences:

- [Wikipedia's article on Windows XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP) details the history of the product and miscellaneous interesting facts related to the topic. You would use this resource if you wanted to write a paper on Windows XP.
- [Microsoft's knowledge-base articles on Windows XP](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=updating%20windows%20xp&ac=2) are focused on solving particular problems users have that relate to Windows XP. You would use this resource if you were looking for a solution to a technical problem or needed very detailed instructions on how to perform a particular task.

Comment: Thank you for your well written and thoroughly referenced points!  Yes these site pages will very much be like the knowledge-base that you describe and not a wiki.  I like how Microsoft uses the TechNet name to name their collection of pages and uses the words knowledge base throughout the site.  It looks like the TechNet name contains subsections of knowledge based pages, wiki pages and library pages.  I think knowledge-base is the best description of the site pages I am trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

If the pages contain things like basic information, style guides and recommendations for non-beginner students, perhaps:

- Guides
- Essentials
- Fundamentals
- Info Hub

Or if it includes a lot of beginner information, perhaps something like:

- Grassroots
- Groundwork

Comment: Thanks for the additional idea's! I suppose I will have to pick from what is posted so far as there are likely not very many suitable alternative words left.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply call the link to the pages *Research*.  This conveys everything that you said.  You don't need a techie name that will confuse people unless there is a point to it (there isn't here).